# Skype: phantom notification

Tags: linux, ubuntu, skype

I'm using skype 2.1.0.81 on Ubuntu, and I can't wear my earphones because there is some annoying notification sound that occurs randomly. I went to `Notifications` in `Options`, and disabled ALL notifications there - the sound still occurs. I went through all sounds in `/usr/share/skype/sounds`, and this notification is not there! I red through skype and ubuntu forums - still nothing, they only suggest to go to `Notifications` option and do stuff there... Have anyone faced this issue?

---

**Edit**

Stupid me, it was Pidgin who was causing these sounds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never experienced anything like this and can't really figure out what it can come from, but here are some suggestions:

1. First, the config files for each user and profile are in fact stored in ~/.Skype/ . Maybe you could take a look in there.
2. After backup, try erasing your local account (in ~/.Skype/) and see if the same behavior happens with a new account.
3. Also, how did you manage to identify that it was Skype playing the sound? Can't it be another application?
4. Check if you don't have another hidden Skype session running in the background and producing the sounds. A simple "ps ax | grep skype" will be enough to tell.

P.S.: As a general remark, it seems more and more obvious that Skype for linux is dead and will not be maintained. Therefore, bugs and incompatibilities with the windows/mac versions will increase with time.

Comment: I can see this when running `ps ax | grep skype`:
` 1970 ?        Sl     1:21 skype
 5270 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto skype`
So I have 2 skype processes... However, when I run `sudo kill 5270`, is says that there is no such process...

Comment: Ah, stupid me, it was Pidgin causing these sounds... Thank you for your help Christian!

Comment: You're welcome! Good to hear to you solved the issue.